# How do I make an Android app that uses the Firefox web view?

Tags: android, cordova, firefox, android-webview

I'm using [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) and [Apache Cordova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cordova) to develop an Android app.

I've installed the standard [Firefox web browser app on my Android device](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/mobile/).

I'd rather not maintain my own fork of a web browser in my application.
I want to run some HTML, JavaScript, and WebGL stuff that seems to be working fine in the Firefox web browser (but apparently not in the default webview -- being able to switch to a different webview would help me debug where exactly the problem is), plus something else that seems to require a native Android app.

Is there a way to tell Android Studio or Apache Cordova to use the Firefox webview rather than the default webview?

My Android Device is already in Developer Mode, so
on the Android device, I can select
Apps >> Settings >> Developer options,
and then when I choose "WebView implementation",
I hoped to see GeckoView or Firefox,
but currently the only option I see there is "Android WebView".
Is there some way to put some other option on that "Set WebView implementation" option list?

Related:
[Use firefox as render engine for Android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352654/use-firefox-as-render-engine-for-android-webview)

Comment: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView